# How can I change my Magento2 Checkout Page CSS?

Tags: magento2, css, checkout-page

[image]When I tried to change checkout Page CSS,It does not get applied.I used to write my CSS on _extend.less file in my theme folder.This applies for Homepage, Catalog Page, Product Detail Page, Cart Page.But for Checkout Page even after deploying, It does not get applied.Please help me.Below is my code.

```
.opc-wrapper .step-title 

{

    color: #cc0000;

    text-transform: uppercase;

    font-size: 13px;

    font-weight: 600;


}

.opc-wrapper .form-login .fieldset .field .label

{

    color:#646464;

    font-weight:500;

    font-size:13.5px;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Vishali Mariappan Are you making changes in less file?

Comment: Yes.I am @ChintanKaneriya

Comment: Have you moved your less file to your front end theme folder and have you run upgrade and deploy commands?

Comment: I have my _extend.less in Magento/app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less.This less file worked fine for all of pages.Yes I have upgraded and deployed it.But still CSS commands does not get applied.

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of error if it's possible?

Comment: Actually there is no error.But It does not get applied.I will attach screenshot.

Comment: Is there not  way without installing grunt?@ChandraPrakashGupta

Comment: Then you have to override (Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_checkout.less) in your theme directory. then you can change accordingly.

Comment: Can you please say where the default _checkout.less is located?

Answer (score 0):

Run these command again using grunt (If you are using grunt):

grunt:exec themename
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
grunt watch

and then try to edit your file and save.

Comment: I don't use grunt.So can you please give me command to run it on Mac.Often I run "sudo php magento setup:static-content:deploy –f" command for deploying.

Comment: Then it will not work till you install grunt in your system. this url is for grunt installation in Mac : http://www.codebelt.com/javascript/install-grunt-js-on-a-mac/

Comment: You have to override (Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/checkout/_checkout.less) in your theme directory. then you can change accordingly.

Comment: Can you please say where is default _checkout.less located?@Chandra Prakash Gupta

Comment: if your parent theme is luma then go to : vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\checkout\_checkout.less

Comment: and if parent theme is blank then go to : vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\checkout\_checkout.less

Comment: I override _checkout.less file in my theme and it workssss...Thank you so much @ChandraPrakashGupta

Comment: sounds good. cheers :)